# MySQL stored procedure not working and column count error occured

Tags: mysql

I have transferred MySQL community database into enterprise edition. When I'm trying to run Stored procedure or Function error occurred as column count is not match.

Sample query :

```
select `SPECIFIC_NAME` 
from `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`.`ROUTINES`
where `ROUTINE_SCHEMA` = 'information_schema' and 
ROUTINE_TYPE = 'PROCEDURE'
```

Error Message :

```
 Column count of mysql.proc is wrong. 
 Expected 20, found 16. The table is probably corrupted
```

What changes can I do for recover from this issue.

Answer (score 2):

You have transferred the `mysql` system database from your old server, and the two servers do not run the same version.

You might be able to recover the system tables with [`mysql_upgrade`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/mysql-upgrade.html).

If not, try manually running the successive upgrade procedures from the version of your old server to the current version. Follow [this link](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/upgrading.html), you will find older upgrade procedures in the older versions of the manual on the left.

Comment: How to find recover table structure?